# É possível fazer com que o navegador cacheie uma ação do usuário?

Tags: javascript

Eu adicionei um botão em um site para que o usuário possa deixar ele em “modo noturno”. Porém caso ele vá para uma nova notícia, o site estará com o modo noturno desativado.

É possível fazer com que o navegador cacheie essa informação, para que uma vez que ele deixe o modo em modo noturno, as outras notícias que ele acesse já estejam também com essa classe?

```
var menu = document.querySelector('body.single-news');
var button = document.querySelector('button#skin-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var open = menu.classList.contains('light-skin');
    menu.classList.toggle('light-skin');
});
```

Removendo a classe "light-skin" é ativado o modo noturno.

Comment: **Cachear** é um dos verbos mais bonitos que nós trouxemos pro português.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem várias maneiras de implementar isso, só você pode definir qual é a melhor ou mais adequada pro seu projeto.

Minha dica é salvar esta configuração no [**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)

```
function ativarModoNoturno(){
    localStorage.setItem('modo_noturno_ativo', true);
}
```

Aí sempre que for abrir uma página você verifica isso

```
function modoNoturnoAtivo(){
    return localStorage.getItem('modo_noturno_ativo') || false;
}
```

Código adaptado. Considerando que o botão faça a troca de um modo para o outro, independente de qual seja o modo atual (*toggle*, como costuma-se chamar).

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Pega o valor atual do localStorage
    var modoNoturnoAtivo = localStorage.getItem('modo_noturno_ativo') || false;
    // Salva o valor invertido no localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('modo_noturno_ativo', !modoNoturnoAtivo);

    // Código original
    var open = menu.classList.contains('light-skin');
    menu.classList.toggle('light-skin');
});
```

---

Obviamente se você estiver trabalhando com uma tecnologia server-side para montar as páginas será muito melhor salvar uma *flag* no banco de dados e validar isto antes de montar a página.

Comment: Conforme editei o post, eu adicionaria esse função dentro da outra? Ou colocaria alguns "if's" para verificar se existe a classe "light-skin" no body?

Comment: @AndréBisewski Atualizei o código.